# AnimationDrawable lagging

Tags: android, animation, double, lag, animationdrawable

I'm using two voids to make animation because i need diffrent animations in same screen. And this animations for different ImageViews. When i add this two ImageViews at the same time to main screen. They start but lagging. But if i use same animation for diffrent ImageViews there is no problem. Why this lagging happens I use threads to call. Just 2 ImageViews and bitmaps is very tiny and just 3 frames.

**EDIT:**
it was an exported project from eclipse to android studio. I just open new empty project in android studio and copy paste all codes and resources manualy than it just works without any problem.

```
final RelativeLayout btt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear); 

 class MyThread implements Runnable {

                          public MyThread() {
                              ImageView myImage3 ;
                              myImage3 = getimage( 0,btt.getHeight(),700);
                  startAnimation(myImage3);
                              btt.addView(myImage3);
                          }

                          public void run() {
                          }
                      }

                      Runnable r = new MyThread();
                      new Thread(r).start();

 class MyThread implements Runnable {

                          public MyThread() {
                              ImageView myImage4 ;
                              myImage4 = getimage( 0,btt.getHeight(),900);
                  startAnimation1(myImage4);
                              btt.addView(myImage4);
                          }

                          public void run() {
                          }
                      }

                      Runnable r = new MyThread();
                      new Thread(r).start();


     private void startAnimation(ImageView img)
        {

            AnimationDrawable mframeAnimation = null;
            BitmapDrawable  frame1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aa);
            BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bb);
            BitmapDrawable  frame3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cc);


            // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
            int reasonableDuration = 10;
            mframeAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
            mframeAnimation.setOneShot(false); // loop continuously
            mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame1, reasonableDuration);
            mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame2, reasonableDuration);
            mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame3, reasonableDuration);

            img.setBackground(mframeAnimation);

            mframeAnimation.setVisible(true,true);
            mframeAnimation.start();

        }
        private void startAnimation1(ImageView img)
        {
            AnimationDrawable mframeAnimation1 = null;
            BitmapDrawable  frame1a = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d);
            BitmapDrawable frame2a = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e);
            BitmapDrawable  frame3a = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f);


            // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
            int reasonableDuration = 10;
            mframeAnimation1 = new AnimationDrawable();
            mframeAnimation1.setOneShot(false); // loop continuously
            mframeAnimation1.addFrame(frame1a, reasonableDuration);
            mframeAnimation1.addFrame(frame2a, reasonableDuration);
            mframeAnimation1.addFrame(frame3a, reasonableDuration);

            img.setBackground(mframeAnimation1);

            mframeAnimation1.setVisible(true,true);
            mframeAnimation1.start();

        }
```

Comment: Your question it is not very clear. May you try to improve it ?

Comment: Trying making almost everything a global and defined in the onCreate. Loading bitmaps takes a lot of resources and best to be done while loading. So then all that would be left would be:  private void startAnimation(ImageView img)
        {
mframeAnimation.setVisible(true,true);
            mframeAnimation.start();
}

Comment: it was an exported project from eclipse to android studio. I just open new empty project in android studio and copy paste all codes and resources manualy than it just works without any problem.